# Read Nodes of an Irregular Shape

Tags: svg

hi i am working on SVG.... I want to Read the nodes of an element, which are in a lot of numbers, but the nodes which i am going to read are of irregular shape, and i have to apply the restriction also on it...Can anyone help...Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: Please clarify. Thing I don't understand: 1) "are in a lot of numbers" - do you mean there are numeric values in attributes? Text Nodes? Paths? What? 2) "nodes are of irregular shape" - what exactly does this mean? Nodes, as in points of a path or shape? 3) "have to apply a restriction" - What type of restriction? On what exactly?